# Shortcode inside a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

I am looking for a slider that would be able to display shortcode in WordPress.

For example, I can create a map with the shortcode [awesomeMap id='1']. And I know there are a bunch of sliders out there, but I can't seem to find one where I could add slides that simply consists of 

[awesomeMap id='1'], 

[awesomeMap id='2'], 

[awesomeMap id='3']

And then when I call [show-slider], it would give me a slider with 3 maps. I'm trying to setup the WordPress so that people taking care of it in the future won't have to touch the code too much...

Anyone know of a WordPress slider that would support this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Layerslider](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246).

It's a pretty robust slider, responsive, and allows the use of shortcodes by providing a place for HTML. I've used this plugin on several projects and just tested it with a map shortcode on one of my sites. Seems to work well. It's always possible you run into plugin conflicts, but it may work for you.